# xmonad on debian: how to change screen resolution

Tags: macos, debian, vmware-fusion, xmonad

I've installed xmonad in a debian vmware vm on osx.  In Gnome I changed the screen resolution to 1440/900 using the GUI menu but this change did not affect the resolution I get when I'm logged in with xmonad as the window manager. I'd really like normal screen resolution in xmonad. How can I make that happen? Change a config file? Do something on the commandline?

Answer (score 7):

I finally found out how to do this (for one session, I haven't figured out how to keep the change when I log out yet):

1. Log in with xmonad.
2. Open run terminal (shift+alt+return).
3. Enter command `xrandr -s 1440x900` then press enter.  Where 1440x900 is of course the screen resolution.

Comment: Seems like `xrandr --query` will also give you a list of available resolutions.

Comment: This solves an issue of apps in xmonad not going full screen.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.xinitrc` file or .xsession to load up during startup:

```
xrandr --output Virtual-0 --mode 1440x900
```

Note, **Virtual-0** is the Display name.  To get the name of the Display on your system, just type `xrandr` in a terminal while the x-server is running.